# How do I use the value of a webform_field as the default-value for a later webform_field?

Tags: 8, webforms

Is there a way with Drupal 8 Webform UI to set the default value of a text field as the value of an earlier text field in the same form, and update via Ajax?

example:

```
user_name:
     '#type': textfield
     '#title': 'User Name'

nick_name:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': 'Nick Name'
    '#default_value': '[webform_submission:values:user_name]'
    '#ajax': true
```

But the default value does not render the token and just prints plain text.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'No' to using tokens to sync two element values, unless the two elements are on different pages. The simplest solution is a write a little JavaScript to sync the nickname with the username.

You can search for examples of [sync'ing two input fields](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20sync%20two%20input%20fields).

The Webform module's Options admin widget uses a little JS to sync an option's value with the option's text. @see [webform.element.options.admin.js](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/js/webform.element.options.admin.js)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to add in some JS that changes the value of the desired field based on input from another field - if it is empty.